Object Set to Front Orthographic View Changes to Perspective View When Exported as a .glt
I changed the camera for my object from perspective to othorgraphic view so that my 3D image displays as if it is a 2D image. When I render the animation in Blender everything is fine, but when I export my file as a .glt my object displays in perspective view. Is there an export setting that can fix this?

